# How to pass multiple consumer names in pact provider JUnit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, pact

Using the pact provider JUnit 5/Spring Boot support annotations, perhaps I am not searching well for the answer... I'm wondering if it's possible to annotate a pact provider verification test with multiple consumers using the `@Consumer` annotation.

Like I would want to be able to do something like the following

```
@Provider("provider-name")
@Consumer("consumer-1, consumer-2")
@PactBroker
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PactVerificationTest {

    @Test
    //test methods
    //...
}
```

The annotation takes a String as a value so unfortunately something like `@Consumer({"consumer-1", "consumer-2"})` does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```java
@PactBroker(consumerVersionSelectors = {
        @VersionSelector(consumer = "my-consumer-1"),
        @VersionSelector(consumer = "my-consumer-2")
})
```

Use the latest library version and see [documentation](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/junit) for more

Comment: Thanks for finding this! The documentation is quite wide-spanning,..